# One vs all Linear SVM Cross validation -Parameter selection

Tags: svm, cross-validation

I'm performing one vs all classification (SVM) for a dataset. Since I'm using a linear SVM the parameters I need to tune and select are-Tolerance and C.  I'm a bit confused on how to go about doing this using a 10-fold cross validation. My understanding is as follows:

- Fold1: For different combinations of (Tolerance, C) choose the combination which give the best accuracy(Im using a one vs all classifier )
- Fold 2: Repeat the same
  .....
- Fold 10: Repeat the same.

So now how will I choose the best combination of (Tolerance, C) given I have ten such combinations?

Answer (score 4):

You may be misunderstanding how cross-validation is used to select hyper-parameters.

1. **Choose a candidate value for each hyper-parameter.** In other words, pick one value for $C$ and one value for $\epsilon$. If you decide to test different kernels, choose the kernel here too. This is traditionally done using a grid search, but there are other methods which may be smarter.
2. **Run the whole cross-validation procedure with the selected parameters.**
3. **Measure the classifier's performance across all cross-validation folds.** The choice of performance measurement is up to you--accuracy, AUC, precision/recall, etc--as is how you combine these measurements from each fold (but you probably want to find the mean or median).
4. **Repeat steps 1-3**, choosing different values for $C$ and $\epsilon$ each time. The number of repeats performed here need not be related to the number of folds in the cross validation performed in steps 2-3.
5. Finally, **choose the pair of parameters** that give you the highest average performance. These should be selected together; don't choose the best $C$ and the best $\epsilon$ separately.

Note that if you're comparing several different models (e.g., a neural network, Naive Bayes, and this SVM), this procedure needs to be "nested" inside the outer cross-validation that is used to compare those models.

Comment: .....Thanks for the detailed explanantion.I have a related doubt-while using the Grid Search to estimate parameters for my Linear SVM in scikit-learn The "accuracy measures" are precision and recall.By selecting the parameters for the model which gives a high precision I get an 81% accuracy rate on my test set-Would this be appropriate to use?(When I manually wrote a k-fold cross validation I used the model parameters which gave me the highest average accuracy)

Comment: Just to make my question clearer-When I use accuracy I can understand the measure.But Im not sure how I would intepret "precision" and "recall" from a 2-class classification perspective.Also is there any way I can incorporate accuracy in the scikitlearn grid search instead of precision/recall?

Comment: You should choose a performance measure that gives you useful information about the task. Precision/Recall are traditionally used when one class is "interesting" and the other is not, as in a search engine, which has relevant results (that you care about) and irrelevant ones (which you don't). Accuracy (or AUC) might be better if you're interested in both classes.

Comment: As for scikit, are you using grid_search.GridSearchCV? If so, it takes a scorer object that calculates the classifiers' performance. I think the default scorer is accuracy, but you can change it: See the docs [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter)